# Removing checkboxes from Qt

Tags: python, pyqt5

I started using Qt for a project and have an issue when removing checkboxes. I have checkboxes on a gridLayout that the user is supposed to be able to add and remove. My issue is that I can remove the checkboxes (I have used removeWidget() and deleteLater() methods) but the grid layout does not update and move the other checkboxes accordingly.

Before removing:

[image]

After Removing:

[image]

Comment: I think it's because Grid Layout is not supposed to do that. You may want to consider using combination of `horizontal` and `vertical` layouts instead of using `QGridLayout`. QGridLayout is tabular that has cells as separate grid.

Comment: Exactly as @ThePyGuy said. Imagine the grid layout as a table, where every widget can occupy one cell (or more, when spanning): deleting the content of a cell in a table doesn't move the content of the other cells. You have to do that.